# Load JSON file to datalist input

Tags: javascript, datalist

I want to load to `datalist` from a JSON file. My JSON file has 2 attributes and looks like:

```
[ {
    "product":"1235",
    "description":"description 1"
  },
  {
    "product":"1325",
    "description":"description 2"
  }, 
  ...
]
```

And the JavaScript code

```
var dataList = document.getElementById('json-datalist');
var input = document.getElementById('ajax');
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
  if (request.readyState === 4) {
    if (request.status === 200) {
      // Parse the JSON
      var jsonOptions = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

      // Loop over the JSON array.
      jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {
        // Create a new <option> element.
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        // Set the value using the item in the JSON array.
        option.value = item;
        // Add the <option> element to the <datalist>.
        dataList.appendChild(option);
      });

      // Update the placeholder text.
      input.placeholder = "e.g. datalist";
    } else {
      // An error occured :(
      input.placeholder = "Couldn't load datalist options :(";
    }
  }
};

// Update the placeholder text.
input.placeholder = "Loading options...";

// Set up and make the request.
request.open('GET', 'myfile.json', true);
request.send();
```

The state is at "Loading options" and doesn't change. If I alter the JSON, like

```
[ 
   "product",
   "description"
]
```

Then it works and "product", and "description" are shown as possible choices.. What I have to edit in the JavaScript in order to show only the element `product`?

Comment: Are you sure the request was loaded? What does it say in the developer console?

Comment: yes it is loaded.. there is no error in developer console..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set the option value to an object:

```
option.value = item;
```

To use just the `product` member, do so explicitly:

```
option.value = item.product;
```

You could also include the description as the visible option text:

```
option.text = item.description;
```

```js
var dataList = document.getElementById('json-datalist');

var jsonOptions = [{
  "product": "1235",
  "description": "description 1"
}, {
  "product": "1325",
  "description": "description 2"
}];

// Loop over the JSON array.
jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  
  option.value = item.product;
  option.text = item.description;

  dataList.appendChild(option);
});
```

```html
<select name="" id="json-datalist">
</select>
```

Comment: I posted one more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090500/selecting-from-datalist-then-fill-another-input if you have any idea.. thx!